# Retag Request/Tag Merge Request for Super User: 'windows7' and 'windows-7'

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

The 'windows-7' tag has 1752 questions, while the 'windows7' tag has only 2.

Keep: 'windows-7'

Comment: This will just keep on popping up until the blacklist gets its way.

Answer (score 7):

Small is the number
Retag done manually
It's all good for now.

Comment: Hehe, nice one; cute. :)

Comment: +1.  There aren't enough near-haiku answers out there.